# Passing C++ command line arguments inside main(), yet do the same job

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to keep the command line argument as standard and yet pass the `argv` internally inside the main?

Like, change this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    App app(argc,argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

to something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<string> argv ="arguments";
    int argc = X;
    App app(argc,argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I have:

```
./a.out -a A -b B -c C
```

I know this is weird. I just want to find a workaround not to change the source code of a huge project and just run my command line arguments every time with only `./a.out`.

Comment: How can you declare variables that match the name of parameters to the same function? It's a conflict the compiler cannot resolve.

Comment: @JonathanWood, I see the point. It was just an example. Consider using another name. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? You already have an array, you already have a size, and it's allocated for you and guaranteed to exist until the end of the program.

Comment: @Alexander, I want my command line arguments to be hidden in the binary and won't be visible as a process. (I know there are ways to mask that, still prefers this). Is there a way?

Comment: Rather than hacking code, why not define an alias, or link to a different target and make `a.out` a shell script that launches that target with the parameters?

Comment: thanks, @ken. still, this parameter would be known when passed. right?

Comment: You basically want to be able to write `./a.out` instead of `./a.out -a A -b B` and have it do the same thing?

Comment: @super, correct

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to make a bash script then modifying your code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
const char *myArgv[]={"-a","A","-b","B"};
int myArgc=4;
App app(myArgc,myArgv);
return app.exec();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not compile in standard C++. You'd need to change it to `const char* myArgv[]`. But then the `App` constructor would need to have a matching signature to accept that. If that can be done, then that would be ideal.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes, I was hesitating to add that (rules might be loosened with compiler switches), but here you go. Considering that adding these lines means a rebuild already, a change in signature may be acceptable too.

Comment: @tevemadar, i am receiving `error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @tevemadar, actually without `const` it is compiled and working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put each of your arguments in a char array, and then put pointers to those arrays into an array of pointers.

```
char arg1[] = "./a.out";
... 
char argN[] = "whatever";
char* argv[] = { arg1, ..., argN}

App app(N, argv);
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. I guess your answer could be OK. Updated my question by the way. let me try yours

Comment: @Amir: I may have completely misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking how you could create arguments to pass to a function with the same signature as main. i.e. `func(int, char**)`, but not simply using the actual arguments to main. Or are you asking how to put the arguments passed to main into a vector?

Comment: Yes. I wanna create arguments to pass to main (as main is) but instead of getting it from the command line, I want to hardcode them inside main and just run `./a.out` instead of `./a.out -a A -b B ...`

Comment: @Amir: Yes, that is what I thought, and what this is the answer to.

Comment: great, let me try then. Do you include `-a A` in one char or separate?

Comment: @Amir: They should be separate if your shell would pass them as separate to your program. In that case, yes, they would be separate, in any shell I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);
```

Comment: Thanks @Soronel, and how am I gonna pass the argv string here? say I have "-a A -b B"

Comment: If this answers the question somehow, then I've completely misunderstood it.

Comment: If this answers the question somehow it needs to be stated how. Mere code is not an answer. It seems to me that this code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You may rename arguments passed to `app` as you wish to avoid a name conflict, for ex.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<string> app_argv = /* contents */;
    int app_argc = app_argv.size() ;
    App app(app_argc, app_argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```